# Why is a class variable not accessible from a method?

Tags: python, namespaces, scope

Consider:

```
class Foo:
    a = 1
    def bar():
        print(a)
```

I expected `a` to be available to the method by scoping rules:  local first, then enclosing, ...

The class `Foo` creates a namespace and a scope, does it not?

`bar` creates a scope; isn't it enclosed by the scope of the class?  There is no `a` defined in the scope of `bar`, so I expected it to pick up the class variable from the enclosing scope.

Evidently I'm confused about namespaces and scopes.  I've tried reading up on this, but haven't been able to find definitive clarification on this particular point (`self.a` works, of course).

Comment: Try `Foo.a` instead of `a`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The class body is not a nestable scope, no. The Python [*Execution Model*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html) explicitly excludes it:

> The scope of names defined in a class block is limited to the class block; it does not extend to the code blocks of methods

That's because the body of a class is executed to form the class attributes; see it as a function with locals, and the locals become the attributes of the new class object.

You can then access those attributes either on the class directly (`Foo.a`) or via an instance (where attribute lookup falls through to the class).

Answer (score -1):

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

    def bar(self):
        print(self.a)
```

By using `__init__()` you will be able to pass the variables to other functions.

Comment: This isn't what the OP is asking about. The question is *why* names at the class scope are not accessed in methods, like in nested function scopes.