# why don't closures work within python classes?

Tags: python, class, scope, closures, class-attributes

```
class Example:
    my_list = [1, 2, 3]
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_list = my_list


example = Example()

print(example.my_list)
```

running the above code returns this `NameError: name 'my_list' is not defined`.

```
class Example:
    my_list = [1, 2, 3]
    def __init__(self):
        global my_list
        self.my_list = my_list


example = Example()
```

Using `global` doesn't seem to work either. What could be going on? why can't you `instantiate` an attribute using `global`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python class variable accessible from class method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119489/python-class-variable-accessible-from-class-method)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set `self.my_list = my_list`, because `my_list` is already an attribute of `Example`:

```
class Example:
    my_list = [1, 2, 3]
    def __init__(self):
        pass


example = Example()

print(example.my_list)
```

You could alternatively define `my_list` in the `__init__` method:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_list = [1, 2, 3]


example = Example()

print(example.my_list)
```